# Issue launching Aurora: Access denied to Performance Insights - InvalidParameterCombination

Tags: amazon-aurora

For some reason i just can't get an Amazon Aurora DB launched. I haven't launched one before but have read many Amazon help / instruction pages. Launching other Amazon products did work well after some digging. This one just doesn't. Any suggestions?

Error:
Access denied to Performance Insights (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: 8ef6c7b9-be54-4bd8-aa87-XXXXXXXX)

http://prntscr.com/iug951

Answer (score 1):

Today it works.. selected the same settings as yesterday. All i did different was omit dashes (-) from the database name and other stuff you have to name. If that was the actual cause of the 3h headache yesterday Amazon really sucks it just doesn't tell you that instead of showing a cryptic error message.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue with the same error message, restarting the setup process from the start (with a database name without a dash in it), fixed the issue.

Comment: This should be a comment instead. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment.